# Build a URL from output of shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, compiling, url

On a linux server i have a script that does a curl and returns an output as below:

Script:

```
/usr/bin/curl -k -s https://example.com:18080/seriessnapshot?substringSearch=OpenFin%20Memory | cut --characters=44-51 | sort --unique | sed -e 's/iessnaps//g' -e '/^$/d'
```

Output:

```
AP711671
AP714628
AP715911
AP716960
AP717267
AP717938
AP718017
AP718024
AP721570
AP721875
AP722002
AP722622
```

I need to then build a URL from the output for each AP number, so for example i would need the output to return as below for each AP number:

```
http://apRandomNumber.com:1025/
```

everything but the AP is static, the only dynamic part of the URL would be the AP number.

Would it be possible to do this from the same script i use to return just AP numbers and if so how can i incorporate it into that script?

Comment: Pipe it into another `sed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple and easy way is to replace your `sed` command with

```
sed -n -E 's|^AP([[:digit:]]+)$|http://ap\1.ztb.icb.commerzbank.com:1025/|p'
```

- `-n` suppresses the printing of lines so we have better control over which lines actually get printed at the end
- `-E` enables extended regular expressions which make the rest easier
- `^AP([[:digit:]]+)$` matches a whole line starting with `AP` and follewed by numbers, it puts the part between the `()` into `\1`. If you would have a more complex pattern with several `()` parts they would end in `\2` etc.
- the value/content of `\1` is then inserted directly into the replacement
- `p` at the end prints the line (so it prints only those lines where the substitution actually took place)

Comment: or put it in another `-e ...` instead of piping.

Comment: Legend! pipe worked and i am getting the output as described in the question above. Are you able to explain to me the different sections of the sed command and what they do?

Comment: Hi thanks, that worked! it removed/ignored the iessnaps. Sorry for the trouble could you please explain how from the comment above what the extra '/^AP/s at the beginning does? if we already have  ^AP(.+)$ after it.

Comment: @Nikhil The extra `/AP/` isn't even necessary :-)

Comment: you are correct. It was not needed. Thank you for all your help!! much appreciated

Comment: Hi @nohillside do you know once the text file is built, how can then curl each link in the text file and return information to me whether it was able to connect or not ?

Comment: @Nikhil Might be useful to ask a new question on this :-)

Comment: tried to, but someone closed the question saying there is a page where this question is answered but it did not really help me

Comment: @nohillside - if AP was not static and could be any 2 capital letters, how could we change the sed command and instead of specifying AP allow any 2 capital letters and then a set of numbers and add that into the rest of the url?

Comment: @Nikhil Define a variable in the shellscript and use this instead. It might help to read up on shell programming first though (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/shell_scripts/shell_scripts.html, https://www.bash.academy/ and similar)

Comment: @nohillside - i was hoping this could have been done via a bit more regex in the sed command

Comment: @Nikhil The matching part of the substitution is `|^([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]+)$|`, I assume you can figure out the rest :-)

Comment: when trying /usr/bin/curl -k -s https://fft-uat-jtimeseries.intranet.commerzbank.com:18080/seriessnapshot?substringSearch=OpenFin%20Memory | awk -F"." '{print $5}' | sort -u | sed -n -E 's |^([[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]+)$ |http://ap\1.ztb.icb.commerzbank.com:1025/|p' - i get the following return when run sed: -e expression #1, char 78: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @Nikhil The space between `$` and `|` might be an issue. Please try to do some debugging on your own, it's a good way to learn how things work.